# ler arquivo JSON com JS

Tags: javascript, json

tenho esse o seguinte arquivo JSON com o nome teste.json:

```js
"registro":[
{"cnpj":"46148234000117","serie":"1","numero":"1"},
{"cnpj":"46148264000117","serie":"1","numero":"2"},
{"cnpj":"46148224000117","serie":"1","numero":"3"},
{"cnpj":"46148274000117","serie":"1","numero":"4"},
{"cnpj":"46148294000117","serie":"1","numero":"5"},
{"cnpj":"46148204000117","serie":"1","numero":"6"},
{"cnpj":"46148294000117","serie":"1","numero":"7"},
{"cnpj":"46148244000117","serie":"1","numero":"8"},
{"cnpj":"46148247000117","serie":"1","numero":"9"},
{"cnpj":"46148242000117","serie":"1","numero":"10"},

];
```

e tenho essa função JS:

```js
$.getJSON("teste.json", function( data ) {
var registro = data.registro;

$.each(data, function(cnpj, numero){
  registro.push("<li id='" + cnpj +"'>"+ numero + "</li>");
});

$("<ul/>", {
  "class": "my-new-list",
  html: registro.join("")
}).appendTo("body");


});
```

gostaria de listar exatamente como está no no arquivo, mas não sei onde está o erro na minha função

Comment: o erro ocorre onde? "$.getJSON("teste.json", function( data )" ?

Comment: provável, pois não está mostrando nada

Comment: acredito que devo ter que criar um laço de repetição

Comment: e depois preciso verificar se pulou algum número

Comment: coloquei uma resposta, depois verifica ela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo o que eu vi, um problema é nesse "each"

```
  var li = [];
  $.each(registro, function(index, value) { // aqui deveria ser "registro" em vez de "data"
    li.push("<li id='" + value.cnpj + "'>" + value.numero + "</li>"); // push no "li" em vez de "registro"
  });
```

alterei um pouco e coloquei no plunker (coloquei, como exemplo, usando reduce também), dá uma olhada:

https://plnkr.co/edit/vmSFYK?p=preview

Comment: boa, acho que vou criar uma tabela, e mudar o append para table

Comment: no caso teria que mudar o li para <td> ?

Comment: troquei para o seguinte

Comment: var li = [];
  $.each(registro, function(index, value) { // aqui deveria ser "registro" em vez de "data"
    li.push("<li id='" + value.cnpj + "'>" + value.numero + "</li>");
    li.push("<tr>");
    li.push("<td id='"+key+"'>"+value.cnpj+"</td>");
    li.push("<td id='"+key+"'>"+value.numero+"</td>");
    li.push("<td id='"+key+"'>"+val.serie+"</td>");
    li.push("</tr>"); // push no "li" em vez de "registro"
  });

Comment: sim, em vez de <li> seria <td>, conseguiu ?